# ajax outputs only the last record from the loop forEach

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax

ajax the request displays only the last record from the loop, the code below:

```
$.ajax({
                   method: "POST",
                   url: "{{asset('/num')}}",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function (data) {
                       var inf;
                       var json_x = data;
                       json_x.forEach(function(item){
                           inf = '<p>'+ item['id'] +"</p>";
                       });
                       insTabl = document.getElementById('table');
                       insTabl.innerHTML = inf;

                   }
               });
```

sending in `div`  `id='table'`

Comment: Can you report the ajax output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
inf = '<p>'+ item['id'] +"</p>";
```

is overwriting the value of `inf` each time through the loop. As a result, when the loop is over, `inf` simply holds the corresponding value from the last iteration.

To fix it, initialise `inf` as an empty string, *before* the loop:

```
var inf = "";
```

and then replace the line above, inside the loop, with this one, which *appends* to the string:

```
inf += '<p>'+ item['id'] +"</p>";
```

That way, you make the HTML string longer each time through the loop, and end up with the series of paragraphs that I assume you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is overwriting the `inf` variable each time. Instead, try adding to your string on each pass:

```
var inf = '';
var json_x = data;
json_x.forEach(function(item){
  inf += '<p>'+ item['id'] +"</p>";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is this line:

```js
inf = '<p>'+ item['id'] +"</p>";
```

You override the old value, instead of just adding the new value (what I guess is what you are trying). So you might try it like this:

```js
let inf = ""; // you could/should use "let" instead of "var"

//codeline in the callback:
inf += "<p>"+ item['id'] +"</p>";
```